# Como dar zoom em um único painel em um gráfico de facetas do ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de dar *zoom* em um único painel de um gráfico criado com `ggplot::facet_wrap`. Eis um exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- structure(list(
  group = c("J", "K", "L", "M", "J", "K", "L",  "M"),
  coef  = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b",  "b"),
  lower = c( 10,   9,  15,  17,  63,  62,  63, -600),
  value = c( 11,  10,  17,  20,  65,  64,  69,   66),
  upper = c( 12,  11,  19,  23,  67,  66,  76,  600)),
  row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

plt <- ggplot(dados, aes(group, value)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
        facet_wrap(~ coef, scale = "free")

plt
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero dar zoom apenas na faceta do coeficiente *b*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo isso gerando um novo *data.frame* com os valores modificados manualmente, gerando um plot com ele e usando as informações de layout para o gráfico com os dados originais (uma dica que peguei anos atrás, mas não tenho mais a referência):

```
dados.zoom <- dados
dados.zoom[dados$coef == "b" & dados$group == "M", c("lower", "upper")] <- c(61, 78)

data.plt.zoom <- ggplot_build(plt %+% dados.zoom)

data.plt <- ggplot_build(plt)

data.plt$layout$panel_params <- data.plt.zoom$layout$panel_params

plt.zoom <- plot(ggplot_gtable(data.plt))
```

Um dos problemas dessa solução é que o gráfico exportado com os dispositivos padrão do ggplot fica com barras horizontais no grupo com zoom (o gráfico acima foi exportado com o dispositivo nativo da [IDE que uso](https://rkward.kde.org/)):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução simples para isso, isto é, que não envolva editar *grobs* e arranjá-los com `grid`?

Para referência, estou rodando R 4.0.4, com ggplot2 3.3.5, em um PC Debian Linux 11 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser feito usando `coord_cartesian()` e `grid.arrange()`

O primeiro é descrito em **R Package Documentation** [Cartesian coordinates](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggplot2/man/coord_cartesian.html)

> A definição de limites no sistema de coordenadas irá ampliar o enredo (como se estivesse a olhar para ele com uma lupa), e não alterará os dados subjacentes como a definição de limites numa balança.

Baptiste Auguie explica como usar `grid.arrange()` em [Arranging multiple grobs on a page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)

```
require( ggplot2 )
require( purrr )
require( dplyr )
require( gridExtra )


função_de_enredo <- function( dados ){
  ggplot( dados, aes( group, value ))               +
  geom_point()                                      +
  geom_errorbar( aes( ymin = lower, ymax = upper )) +
  facet_wrap( ~ coef, scale = "free" )
}

dados %>%
  filter( coef == "a") %>%
    função_de_enredo ->
      p1

(
  dados %>%
    filter( coef == "b") %>%
      função_de_enredo
) + coord_cartesian( ylim = c( 60, 76 )) ->
      p2

grid.arrange( p1, p2, ncol = 2 )
```

[os resultados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3g86.png)